# Extracting a filed from xml tag

Tags: python, bash, shell, automation, xmllint

In xml file I am searching the sting "<file:write" and xml file has a complete xml tag and with in that tag it has the value field. I am trying to fetch the value filed in csv file with file name. The problem is that the field (path= and Path=) is either 2 or 3 or 4th column and I am not able to use the cut command.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
find /opt/mortagage/application.xml -type f -exec egrep -ri "<file:write" /dev/null {} + |uniq| sed '/<!--.*-->/d' | sed '/<!--/,/-->/d'

/opt/mortagage/application.xml:              <file:write doc:id="16630" path="${file.location}" doc:name="Save file to directory">
/opt/mortagage/application.xml:                      <file:write doc:name="Write to complete folder" doc:id="18890" path='#["${file.completeLocation}" ++ vars.zipFileName]' config-ref="File_Config_completed">
/opt/mortagage/application.xml:                      <file:write doc:name="Write to complete folder" doc:id="19990" Path='#["${file.completeLocation}" ++ vars.zipFileName]' config-ref="File_Config_completed">
```

Comment: A "better way" would be to use dedicated processors for structured data, in this case a command-line XML processor could do it easily. Some options: [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), [libxml/xmllint](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/wikis/home), [saxonica/saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml), etc.

Comment: @pmf can you help me with some xmllint command which can help in pulling the data?

Answer (score 0):

> A "better way" would be to use dedicated processors for structured data, in this case a command-line XML processor could do it easily.

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
xq -r '.. | ."file:write"? | arrays[] // . | ."@path", ."@Path" | strings' in.xml
```

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (which completely ignores namespaces):

```bash
yq -oy '.. | .write? | select(kind == "map") // .[] | ."+@path" // ."+@Path"' in.xml
```

Using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//file:write' -v '@path' -v '@Path' -n in.xml
```

Using [libxml/xmllint](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/wikis/home):

- `xmllint` requires to either declare the actual namespaces (which you haven't provided in the sample), or to defect to ignoring them all by resorting to a `local-name()` check
- `xmllint` also doesn't support the `string(…)` function on multiple matches, so the best it can do is to output full attribute nodes like  `path="${file.location}"`. A workaround could be to subsequently use another tool (like `awk` or `sed`) to trim them down.

```bash
xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="write"]/@path | //*[local-name()="write"]/@Path' in.xml |
  sed 's/^.*\?="\|"$//g' # removes all up to the first =" and a final "
```

All of them output something like:

```
${file.location}
#["${file.completeLocation}" ++ vars.zipFileName]
#["${file.completeLocation}" ++ vars.zipFileName]
```

Comment: A slightly different version with `xmllint`: `xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="write"]/@*[name()="path" or name()="Path"]' test.xml | cut -d '=' -f2 | tr -d '"'`. Tested.

Comment: @LMC Using `or` instead of the full-blown `|` construct is a good point! For changing the `sed` command to `cut` and `tr`, I'd recommend using `-f2-` (to `cut` from the second column up to the end) instead, to handle cases where the value itself also contains `=` signs. And as for `tr`, which eliminates **all** occurrences of `"`, I don't know how reliable xmllint's output encoding is. Having an input of `path='a"b'` seems to be favorably returned as `path="a&quot;b"`, but are there really no edge cases where something is converted into `\"` or similar such that another `"` could still occur?

Comment: xmllint is from libxml2 project so I believe it's encoding is very reliable. Not sure about those edge cases but some simple tests could give more info.

Comment: single quotes are shown as single quotes, double quotes are converted to the entity `path="'some' &apos;some&apos;"` -> `path="'some' 'some'"`